# Image Theory in Electrodynamics

Tags: partial-differential-equations, physics, electromagnetism

I'm searching for a rigorous mathematical proof of the image theorem for electric/magnetic currents distributions. A proof that, I think, shows that removing the reflecting surface and placing equivalent current sources, boundary conditions of fields are satisfied.

Do you have some references for such a proof?

Thanks.

Comment: It's not really a theory on its own, it's a consequence of theorems realting to the existence and uniqueness of solutions to differential equations with prescribed boundary conditions.

Comment: Yes, it's true. I've used an improper name.

Comment: The textbook arguments I remember seem OK. (Sometimes physics "proofs" are not, see my answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/350394/85443).)

Comment: The proof is just the uniqueness of the solutions to Laplace's equation. Any potential (regardless of if it is from a uniform or discrete charge distribution or a series of conductors or anything else) that satisfies both Laplace's equation and the given boundary conditions must be the ONLY solution for that set of boundary conditions. The method of images can be used in many more cases than just the case of the infinite conducting surface.

Comment: In an electrodynamic problem I have only the vector potential A, I don’t use the scalar potential V (due to Lorenz Gauge). So, I have to show that both real problem and image problem satisfy the same boundary condition, right?